# Using Image Magick to measure "Cloudiness" of the Sky

Tags: imagemagick, cloud, percentage, weather

I came across another thread:

[In a digital photo, how can I detect if a mountain is obscured by clouds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528356/in-a-digital-photo-how-can-i-detect-if-a-mountain-is-obscured-by-clouds)

about analysing images
but I couldn't work out how to go from that to what I would like to do, which seems to be somewhat similar.

Basically, I want to take an image of the sky (only 640 x 480) and measure how "blue" it is - or how grey/cloudy. I have plenty of comparison images I could use and am not sure whether to try and use convolution or just some type of histogram measurement.

Ideally, I'd like to come with a percentage figure which approximates to the "blueness" of the image.

Any thoughts/ideas or example commands/scripts would be wonderful.

Thanks for reading.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an image processing specialist, but I would imagine that if you convert the image to the HSV color space, all of the pixels representing a unobstructed part of the sky will have a high saturation and a hue close to blue. I would ignore the value channel because brightness changes with time of day. just set your hue and saturation threshold appropriately, and count pixels, and see how many cloud vs sky pixels you get.

Not sure how well it will work but it's an idea.

Comment: Thanks - but do you know the imagemagick commands which could perform these operations?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question last month after adding a camera module to my raspberry pi based weather station.

I tested this imagemagick command :

```
convert file.jpg -colors 8 -format "%c" histogram:info:
```

to get the 8 most represented colors of this sky part in RGB format.

I figured out that you can evaluate a pourcentage from those 3 numbers and a grey image (cloudy) is something as 33% 33% 33%. I didn't do it, but with awk command or some perl, you might be able to do that.

But here (in Congo), a blue sky is not so far from a grey sky. So it's not the perfect method to compute a cloudiness factor. Instead, it will be a not so bad idead to compute the variance to see if you have clouds or uniform colored sky. Or maybe compute both and see what append. If you do that several time by hour, you can track some evolution ?

After reading EternityForest answer, I figured out that you can use

```
-colorspace HSB
```

or

```
-colorspace HSL
```

in my previous command. If you put 1 instead of 8, you will get the most represented value.

Some discussions about this on [imagemagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12878&sid=4ddf0543400861c0902fb1b2953a22af)

I will stay connected to this thread cause I'm really interested solving this cloudiness question too !

Good luck,

Greg.